# How to make AWS API gateway to "understand" trailing slash?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway configured such that `/auth` method calls a Lambda.
However, an existing product tries to call `/auth/` with trailing slash and it ends up as error 404.

What can I do so that `/auth/` URL goes to the same route as `/auth` in the API Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the way to solve it is to configure the path like so (Terraform code from API Gateway config)

**WAS**

```
    "GET /auth" = {
      integration_type        = "AWS_PROXY"
      integration_http_method = "POST"
      payload_format_version  = "2.0"
      lambda_arn              = module.my-lambda.this_lambda_function_invoke_arn
    }
```

(this makes `/auth` work)

**NOW**

```
    "GET /auth/{proxy+}" = {
      integration_type        = "AWS_PROXY"
      integration_http_method = "POST"
      payload_format_version  = "2.0"
      lambda_arn              = module.my-lambda.this_lambda_function_invoke_arn
    }
```

(this makes `/auth/` work and breaks `/auth`).

Comment: How can this be the answer if it breaks /auth? Understand this is old, but any chance you know if you were able to pass both path?

Comment: You don't have to "break" anything. This does work. You can just include both routes!

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the route as `ANY /{proxy+}` so that any HTTP method (GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE) for any routes are directed to the same handler. Alternatively, you could also specify the HTTP method to narrow it down, like `POST /{proxy+}`.

So...

> What can I do so that /auth/ URL goes to the same route as /auth in the API Gateway?

Technically speaking, this solves your problem, but now it is up to you to differentiate routes and know what to do.

As far as I know, this is the only way to achieve it with API Gateway, since according to some RFC out there routes "/auth" and "/auth/" are actually different routes and API Gateway complies with that RFC.

This is what I ended up doing (using the `ANY /{proxy+}`) and, if it is any help, this is the code I have to handle my routes and know what to do:

```js
// Queue.ts

class Queue<T = any> {
  private items: T[];

  constructor(items?: T[]) {
    this.items = items || [];
  }

  get length(): number {
    return this.items.length;
  }

  enqueue(element: T): void {
    this.items.push(element);
  }

  dequeue(): T | undefined {
    return this.items.shift()!;
  }

  peek(): T | undefined {
    if (this.isEmpty()) return undefined;
    return this.items[0];
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.items.length == 0;
  }
}

export default Queue;
```

```js
// PathMatcher.ts

import Queue from "./Queue";

type PathMatcherResult = {
  isMatch: boolean;
  namedParameters: Record<string, string>;
};

const NAMED_PARAMETER_REGEX = /(?!\w+:)\{(\w+)\}/;

class PathMatcher {
  static match(pattern: string, path: string): PathMatcherResult {
    const patternParts = new Queue<string>(this.trim(pattern).split("/"));
    const pathParts = new Queue<string>(this.trim(path).split("/"));

    const namedParameters: Record<string, string> = {};
    const noMatch = { isMatch: false, namedParameters: {} };

    if (patternParts.length !== pathParts.length) return noMatch;

    while (patternParts.length > 0) {
      const patternPart = patternParts.dequeue()!;
      const pathPart = pathParts.dequeue()!;

      if (patternPart === "*") continue;
      if (patternPart.toLowerCase() === pathPart.toLowerCase()) continue;
      if (NAMED_PARAMETER_REGEX.test(patternPart)) {
        const [name, value] = this.extractNamedParameter(patternPart, pathPart);
        namedParameters[name] = value;
        continue;
      }

      return noMatch;
    }

    return { isMatch: true, namedParameters };
  }

  private static trim(path: string) {
    return path.replace(/^[\s\/]+/, "").replace(/[\s\/]+$/, "");
  }

  private static extractNamedParameter(
    patternPart: string,
    pathPart: string
  ): [string, string] {
    const name = patternPart.replace(NAMED_PARAMETER_REGEX, "$1");
    let value = pathPart;
    if (value.includes(":")) value = value.substring(value.indexOf(":") + 1);
    return [name, value];
  }
}

export default PathMatcher;
export { PathMatcherResult };
```

Then, in my lambda handler, I do:

```js
const httpMethod = event.requestContext.http.method.toUpperCase();
const currentRoute = `${httpMethod} ${event.rawPath}`;

// This will match both:
// GET /products/asdasdasdas
// GET /products/asdasdasdas/
const match = PathMatcher.match("GET /products/{id}", currentRoute);

if (match.isMatch) {
  // Here, the id parameter has been extracted for you
  const productId = match.namedParameters.id;
}
```

Of course you can build a registry of routes and their respective handler functions and automate that matching process and passing of parameters, but that is the easy part.